# How should I convert my air conditioner outlet for the new unit?

Tags: electrical

I purchased a new window AC without paying attention to the plug type & amperage. I currently have a dedicated 30A breaker for my old AC but my new AC is 15amp. What's the most economical way to get my new AC to work with my existing set-up?

[image]

Comment: Is the "3600W" and the '15A" the maximum rating of the plug (so the requirement for the breaker) or is it the actual power and current that the a/c unit causes to flow?  Maybe this requires a 20 A breaker. Does the new plug fit in the old receptacle?

Comment: What is the BTU/h rating for this a/c unit? Do the installation instructions state what the current draw is at maximum setting? What do the instructions state about the circuit requirements?

Answer (score 9):

A new outlet so the plug will fit.

You must also change the breaker to limit the circuit to 15 amps, to match the outlet.  Before the edit I was thinking this was in a different code region.  Thanks to Ecnerwal for pointing out my mistake.

If something does happen, you want the breaker to trip as soon as possible.  A 30 amp breaker will take much longer to trip, if it trips at all.

Wires will be okay since you are reducing the amps it can use.

Comment: You **MUST** reduce (replace) the breaker to match the outlet here. It's not *optional.* The wires are safe for 30A (presuming the old one is done correctly) but you cannot over-amp receptacles (unless you have multiple 15A receptacles on the circuit, where you can run a 20A breaker as a special case.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal  As those plugs are not US type I imagine they are under different code.  I did not want to say OP must in case their code is not the same as ours, but it is a very good idea to change.

Comment: NEMA 6-30P and NEMA 6-15P and very much US type. Just US 240V type.

Comment: @Ecnerwal   My mistake then.  Just got European plug looking into my mind for some reason.  Will edit the answer.

Comment: What do the instructions with the a/c unit state about the circuit requirements?

Comment: When you replace the breaker, make sure to label that circuit to be compatible with 30A.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Just as I thought, replacing the plug & 30amp breaker is my only option. While I'm waiting on my electrician, I got the following product to use temporarily. Any opinions on this?

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B084141DMX?ref_=pe_386300_442618370_TE_sc_as_ri_0&th=1

Comment: That product does seem to be UL and CSA listed, so it should work.  If you own your detached home then changing a plug and breaker are not that hard to do yourself if comfortable.  Turn off the main breaker first.  Take before and after pictures.